# Why using cgroup can’t restrict cpu resource?

Tags: php, cgroups

I want using cgroup to restrict cpu resource for per-group under CentOS 7. I have added two groups in OS, one group of them has website – web2, another group has website – web3, I follow this link type command line step by step.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/ch-using_control_groups

1.

```
yum install libcgroup-tools
```

2.In the /etc/cgconfig.conf file

```
group client0 {
        cpu {
                cpu.shares="250";
        }
        cpuacct {
                cpuacct.usage="0";
        }
        memory {
                memory.limit_in_bytes="2G";
                memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes="3G";
        }
}

group client1 {
        cpu {
                cpu.shares="500";
        }
        cpuacct {
                cpuacct.usage="0";
        }
        memory {
                memory.limit_in_bytes="4G";
                memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes="6G";
        }
}
```

3. in the /etc/cgrules.conf file

```
@client0 cpu,cpuacct,memory     client0
@client1 cpu,cpuacct,memory     client1
```

4.

```
service cgconfig restart; service cgred restart
```

5.in the cpu.sh file

```
x=0
while [ True ];do
    x=$x+1
done;
```

I testing it to use this two command line:

```
sudo -u web2 sh /tmp/cpu.sh &
sudo -u web3 sh /tmp/cpu.sh &
```

It does worked, one is twice than the another. But the other way, I wrote loop code to consume cpu resource and  I visiting two websites in browser, then I go to OS and type command – top, I see two line, the command row is php-fpm, the %cpu row’s value is the same, It's incorrect, should be one is twice than the another. What's wrong?